# validation fails on SecurePassword Virtual Attributes on custom create at Activerecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, omniauth, activemodel

I'm trying to mix a custom User authentication mechanism based on SecurePassword with Facebook integration through omniauth-facebook gem.

my app uses Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.0.

i tried to follow this guide [omniauth](http://blog.railsrumble.com/2010/10/08/intridea-omniauth/) and some other articles to came up with something like this for the User and Authentication Models

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :user_playlist
has_one :user_info

has_many :band_likes
has_many :song_likes

has_many :band_comments
has_many :song_comments

has_many :authorizations

#many to many relation between User and Band
#todo: make a bands_users migration
has_and_belongs_to_many :bands


has_secure_password

validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, length: {in: 8..64}, format: {with: /\A[a-zA-Z ]+\Z/, message: 'Debe poseer solo letras y espacios.'}
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, format: {with: /@/, message: 'Dirección de correo inváilda.'}
validates :password, length: {in: 8..24}
validates :password_confirmation, length: {in: 8..24}

def self.create_from_hash!(hash)
        create(:email => hash['info']['email'], :username => hash['info']['name'], :password => hash['uid'], :password_confirmation => hash['uid'] )
end
end
```

Authorization Model:

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates_presence_of :user_id, :uid, :provider
validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

def self.find_from_hash(hash)
  find_by_provider_and_uid(hash['provider'], hash['uid'])
end

def self.create_from_hash(hash, user = nil)
  user ||= User.create_from_hash!(hash)
  Authorization.create(:user => user, :uid => hash['uid'], :provider => hash['provider'])
end
end
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  unless @auth = Authorization.find_from_hash(auth)
    # Create a new user or add an auth to existing user, depending on
    # whether there is already a user signed in.
    @auth = Authorization.create_from_hash(auth, current_user)
  end
  # Log the authorizing user in.
  self.current_user = @auth.user

  render :text => "Welcome, #{current_user.username}. <br />User saved = #{current_user.save} .<br/>User valid = #{current_user.valid?}.<br />errors= #{current_user.errors.full_messages}"
end

end
```

The last render was written to check about the fact that my password does not gets validated, it doesn't matter if i use hash['uid'], hash['info']['name'], or whatever.

The reason why i use this values is just because, i will figure out later how to build a random password for the oauth-ed user, but i don't want blank ones nor disable the validations.

but, no matter what value i use, always get only my name and email:

```
*Welcome, "My Real Name Here.
User saved = false.
User valid = false.
errors= ["Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)", "Password confirmation is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"]*
```

When creating users in Rails Console got no problem, just when OAuth tries to create a User with create_from_hash.

also, if i try to assign a non existing value from hash to password fields, it adds the message that can be blank. so, it isn't blank.

and rendering hash['uid'] in controller shows that it's longer than 8.

I Must warn that i'm new to rails, so if you can, explain me with apples xD

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

finally i came up with this on User model:

```
def self.create_from_hash!(hash)
   self.where(:email => hash.info.email.to_s).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = hash.info.email
      user.username = hash.info.name
      user.password = hash.uid
      user.password_confirmation = hash.uid
   end
end
```

I don't know why the later doesn't work but at least this one works!

Greetings!